# Create script to do a monitoring job on domain and website certificate

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl

I have to create a script to :

1. list all certificate on Azure platform,
2. including expiration date
3. including sending an alert before expiration in order to anticipate the update.

All SSL certificate and VM and Webapp and websites must be included.

Actually I have started by looking  on the internet and I have found some script but I would like to learn.

I have made some changes on my script so i can adapt it to the environment.

List all certificate on vault (NOK)

List certificate on a subscription (ok)

Include alert on expire date (NOK)

```
# Connect to Azure 
Write-Host "Login to Azure"
Login-AzureRmAccount
# Select $subscription
Write-Host "Select subscription $subscription"
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

Comment: It is not clear what _specifically_ you are stuck on. Ideally, your title should be a clear statement of what particularly you need help on, and not a broad "need help" (which is generally obvious). As it stands, this question is likely to close - so please edit both the title and the body to clarify exactly what you need help on.

Comment: What does NOK mean in the context of the above list?

Comment: Hello , thank you all for reading and helping me ,

Comment: @halfer actually my account level , i think the problem came from here, that's why i cannot list all certificates on vault

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would mention is that you will want to look to use the updated Az Module:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/?view=azps-1.5.0

You will want to use Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate to list the certificates which will include meta-data such as when it expires.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-1.5.0

If I were to send the alert, I would likely use a logic app to coordinate the review and alerting/actions for that.